# join fetch not working in Hibernate Query Language

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I want to retrieve all the records in One database hit and for that, I am using join fetch statements below is my Query

```
String q = "SELECT oneChat from " + Chat.class.getName() + " oneChat "
                + " join fetch oneChat.user1 " 
                + " join fetch oneChat.user2 "
                + " join fetch oneChat.user3 "
                + " join fetch oneChat.groupData "
                + "where oneChat.dmlStatus != :dmlStatusValue"
                + " AND group_id = :groupIdValue" + " AND reference_id = 0"
                + " AND root_chat_id = oneChat.chatId";
```

There are total 4 foreign keys/Joins in my table so I added the join fetch statement but its not working i.e. not returning anything how ever if I remove the join fetch statements I get the result set. My Fetch on table joins is by default Eager ( didn't changed it to Lazy).

Also there's no sql syntax error in the Log file. Am I missing anything ?

**Update:**
It is because the second join i.e. user2 is returning null so I wasn't getting any data. Now if anyone could tell me how can I counter this, the query should be independent it shouldn't rely on data.

Comment: can you add that entity impl? also when you run an sql equivalent to this hql.. do you get results?

Comment: yes I get results.. simple HQL without these join fetch works fine. I get results.

Comment: kindly check the update now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you want to return results regardless of data being present on the dependencies, then you should use left join instead of inner join (join fetch is equal to inner join fetch):

```
"SELECT oneChat from " + Chat.class.getName() + " oneChat "
                + " left join fetch oneChat.user1 " 
                + " left join fetch oneChat.user2 "
                + " left join fetch oneChat.user3 "
                + " left join fetch oneChat.groupData "
                + "where oneChat.dmlStatus != :dmlStatusValue"
                + " AND group_id = :groupIdValue" + " AND reference_id = 0"
                + " AND root_chat_id = oneChat.chatId";
```

Now when the OneChat does not have any user2 dependency on the database, the query will still return results regardless of that.

Just on the side.. if you are using prefixed, then try to add prefixes to `group_id` and `root_chat_id` fields in the where clause for clarity.

Comment: can this affect the data i.e  in sql inner join and left out joins are different right ?

Comment: You will get oneChat entities regardless whether of its 4 dependencies (may have none in that case).. i understood that is waht you are aiming for. If your query needs to be transparent to the existance of only user2 for example then you can left join only that dependency.

Comment: I mean that left join will return all the values from an inner join plus all values in the left table that do not match to the right table, including rows with NULL (empty) values in the link column.